# Insert Into with subquery to insert multiple rows into database

Tags: sql-server, subquery, insert-into

I am struggling to generate a 'notifications' query to work correctly at the moment.

I'm working on a query that will add a string to a table in which will add multiple rows at once, with only one column of which will be changed in this 'bulk insert':

I currently have:

```
    public static void addNotification(string notification)
    {
        SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);

        using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            scmd.Connection = scon;
            scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            scmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO notificationAck (Email, Notification, isAcknowledged) VALUES ((SELECT Email FROM AspNetUsers), '" + notification + "' ,0)";
            scon.Open();
            int status = scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            scon.Close();
        }
    }
```

However, on passing this a string like: "this is a notification", it comes up with the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

So, could someone possibly explain how this query *should be* run?

The table has the columns:

[image]

I understand the 'PK1' isn't the best of practises, but this is only a table for testing purposes (it's set to auto increment)

So, the isAcknowledged should be set to 0, the notification should be this string, and the email should be selected from each row of the table AspNetUsers?

Would anyone e able to explain to me how I should go about adding this data into my db?

Comment: `INSERT iNTO SELECT` does not require `VALUES`: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
scmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO notificationAck (Email, 
                                                 Notification, 
                                                 isAcknowledged) 
                    SELECT Email, '" + notification + "', 0
                    FROM AspNetUsers";
```

`INSERT INTO SELECT` does not require `VALUES`. Hence, you only have to use a `SELECT` statement that retrieves `Email` field from `AspNetUsers` plus two *constant* values.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Reiterating what I've also commented, I didn't realise I had to place the table name at the end of the statement, not within it

Comment: @jbutler483 You' re welcome. Please also note the you should use an `SqlParameter` object in place of `notification` variable. Your code is prone to SQL Injection.

Comment: Admin controls only here :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use `VALUES` when using a query to generate your results. You can change the `INSERT` query to this:

```
INSERT INTO notificationAck (Email, Notification, isAcknowledged) 
SELECT Email, 'SOME STRING', 0 FROM AspNetUsers
```

Which translated in to your code would look like:

```
scmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO notificationAck (Email, Notification, isAcknowledged) 
                    SELECT Email, '" + notification + "', 0 FROM AspNetUsers";
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I didn't realise I had to place the table name at the end, which was causing an issue as well. So thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query

```
SELECT Email FROM AspNetUsers
```

returns more than one row as your error says. You need to change it so that it returns only one row, for example:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Email FROM AspNetUsers
```

Then change your command as below

```
scmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO notificationAck (Email, Notification, isAcknowledged) SELECT TOP 1 Email " + notification + "' ,0 FROM AspNetUsers'";
```

if you want to insert more than one row, the remove top 1 from query.

```
scmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO notificationAck (Email, Notification, isAcknowledged) SELECT Email " + notification + "' ,0 FROM AspNetUsers'";
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, I needed to insert for **each** email returned.

Comment: Okay. It seems that I misunderstood your question. You are right of course.

Answer (score 0):

> Select `Top 1` in Sub Query if you want to insert only 1 row

try

```
INSERT INTO notificationAck (Email, Notification, isAcknowledged) 
VALUES ((SELECT top 1 Email FROM AspNetUsers), '" + notification + "' ,0)
```

> if you want to insert all rows from  AspNetUsers then use

```
 INSERT INTO notificationAck(Email,Notification, isAcknowledged) select 
 Email,''+notification +"',1 from AspNetUsers
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, I needed to insert for **each** email returned.